# In R: Searching a column for different string patterns and replace all of them

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a column with different game titles. In order to collect them, I have to change all of them to a singluar spelling.
For example, I have:

```
str_replace_all(FavouriteGames_DF$FavGame1, pattern = c("SKYRIM|
                                          THE ELDER SCROLLS V: SKYRIM|
                                          ELDER SCROLLS SKYRIM|
                                          ELDER SCROLLS V SKYRIM|
                                          SKYRIM (BETHESDA 2011)|
                                          SKYRIM (MODDED)|
                                          THE ELDERSCROLLS V: SKYRIM"), 
            replacement = "THE ELDER SCROLLS 5: SKYRIM")
```

The problem is, that str_replace_all is kinda bad for this, as it can't just search for any matching pattern and replace it with the replacement, but apparently has to go through it in order and I can't predict where in the DataSet which term will arrive.
I do not want the function to replace incomplete matches (ie., turning "The ELDERSCROLLS V: SKYRIM" to THE ELDERSCOLLS V: THE ELDER SCROLL 5: Skyrim")
Putting the patterns into `pattern = c("1", "2")` it will not work at all, because it can only check for the patterns in order.

I also tried the FindReplace function from the DataCombine package, but that one doesn't seem to work either for reasons I do not quite understand (claiming I am missing dimensions and the vector not being a character vector). Anyway, I want to use as few packages as possible and would prefer to stay in the tidyverse.

Does anybody have a good solution? I do not want to search for each term on it's own as I have to do this a lot and I already have to do it for 6 columns as mutate_at doesn_t seem to work with str_replace.

Thanks!

Comment: Does ```FavouriteGames_DF[FavGame1 %in% pattern, ]$FavGame1 <- replacement``` do what you are trying to do?

Comment: No. It says there it couldn't find object "FavGame1"
Maybe there is a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I used ```data.table``` syntax. Try ```FavouriteGames_DF[FavouriteGames_Df$FavGame1 %in% pattern, ]$FavGame1 <- replacement```

Comment: That seemed to have worked! Thanks a bunch :D
How does this work exactly? The first position is the row, right? So this cicles through every row and checks for the pattern with the %in% command?

Comment: That's right, the statement between [ and the comma , subsets the rows (it takes all the rows for which that statement is ```TRUE```. The ```$FavGame1``` gets the column with the respective name (of the already subsetted data.frame) and then those entries get replaced by ```replacement```. This only works because ```%in%``` is a so-called vectorized function, meaning that it takes a vector as an input (and not just a single value).

Comment: cool. Thanks for the solution and explanation :) That will come in handy

Comment: @NiklasvMoers add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment as an answer:

```
FavouriteGames_DF[FavouriteGames_Df$FavGame1 %in% pattern, ]$FavGame1 <- replacement
```

Answer (score 1):

A handy solution would be to just use "SKYRIM" as a pattern, as it is the common word on all the patterns you specified. You could define a very simple function to check for that pattern and then use `lapply` on the specific column you want to check for:

```
check <- function(x){
    y <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
    if("SKYRIM" %in% y)
        return("THE ELDER SCROLLS 5: SKYRIM")
    else
        return(x)
}

FavouriteGames_DF["FavGame1"] <- lapply(FavouriteGames_DF["FavGame1"], check)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid this would only work for this one example. I have other cases where there is no unified word in the pattern.